# Is there a R function for encoding time series as images with the gramian-angular-fields-method (gaf/gasf)?

Tags: r, encoding, time-series

I want to encode time series as images with the gramian-angular-fields-method (GAF) with the aim to apply convolutional neural networks (CNNs). I haven't found a R function, that implements this so far.

For Python I have found the following:
https://github.com/pecu/Series2GAF

I have also tried to write a function myself, but I am not sure if it works correctly.
This is the article, proposing the GAF-method:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=2ahUKEwjS5a2PxJjiAhUPIlAKHVj4BBMQFjAFegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaai.org%2Focs%2Findex.php%2FWS%2FAAAIW15%2Fpaper%2FviewFile%2F10179%2F10251&usg=AOvVaw0uFl_9ZuLwCRvF_BouOxnV

Here is my code with an example for the time series values stored in x:
x is just a vector with measured values ordered by date, e.g.

```
library('tidyverse')
library('reshape2')
library('ggplot2')

x <- tibble(values = sin(-10:6))
```

Function to replicate the equations 1, 2 and 3 of this article:

```
gramian_angular_field_custom <- function(x){
  # Delete column names
  names(x) <- NULL

  # Convert to matrix
  x <- x %>% as.matrix()

  # Normalize
  x <- (x - max(x) + (x - min(x))) / (max(x) -min(x))
  x <- x %>% as.matrix()

  # Calculate phi for polar coordinates
  x <- x %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(V1 = acos(V1)) %>%
    as.matrix() %>%
    t()

  # Create matrix by column repeat
  x <- x %>%
    t() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    replicate(n = length(x), .) %>%
    bind_cols()

  # Calculate sum of phi
  x <- x + as_tibble(t(x))
  x <- x %>% as_tibble()

  # Calculate cosinus
  x <- x %>% cos()

  x <- x %>% as.matrix()
  colnames(x) <- NULL

  # convert matrix to tibble in long format
  x <- x %>% 
    melt() %>% 
    as_tibble()

  return(x)
}
```

And then apply this function and plot the resulting image:

```
x %>% 
  gramian_angular_field_custom() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var2, Var1)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red')) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

The resulting image is not axisymmetric to the diagonale, as it should be, or am I wrong? Any suggestions on the math is as appreciated as a hint for a R function, that implements this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could use the python module [pyts](https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pyts.image.GramianAngularField.html) and the R package [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) to run python code from R.