# How to call python script/function from within R function?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I would like to write an R function which would take some input data and launch python script to process them. I can use reticulate in R markdown document during RStudio session, but I do not know how to properly call python from within R function. Any example/tip would be apreciated (I have no formal training in coding, so please be kind).

Oh, and for the record, I am trying to launch pyts gasf module from R - my fully R-coded equivalent (similar to this, but based on signal and cimg: [Is there a R function for encoding time series as images with the gramian-angular-fields-method (gaf/gasf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56113791/is-there-a-r-function-for-encoding-time-series-as-images-with-the-gramian-angula)) is slow and produces an array which has to be reshaped in pythonish fashion before it is loaded to Keras.

EDIT:

This is how I am able to execute the command in Rmarkdown document (splitted to 3 chunks for clarity):

````
```{r}
#dummy vector
dummy <- c(601, 629, 652, 688, 653, 633, 625, 622, 653, 667, 605, 595, 667, 653, 
          602, 597, 659, 656, 706, 710, 718, 711, 725, 682, 656, 676, 698, 680, 
          689, 702, 689, 686, 701, 730, 736, 727, 685, 656, 692, 691, 685, 662, 
          678, 695, 720, 718, 694, 701, 713, 724, 685, 665, 664, 702, 680, 685, 
          709, 711, 681, 678, 715, 722, 737, 726, 716, 714, 727, 725, 717, 719, 
          730, 749, 736, 721, 704, 720, 719, 725, 712, 713, 708, 711, 706, 693, 
          682, 693, 701, 702, 699, 696, 693, 688, 695, 694, 687, 687, 699, 707, 
          688, 680)
```


```{r}
# reticulate
require(reticulate); require(tibble)
pyts<- reticulate::import("pyts", convert = TRUE)
pytsImage<-reticulate::import("pyts.image", convert = TRUE)
x<-t(as.ts(dummy))
```


```{python}
# python
from pyts.image import GramianAngularField
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
gasf = GramianAngularField(image_size=15, method='summation')
X_gasf = gasf.fit_transform(r.x)
exit 
```
```{r}
# transform dummy vector
dummy_GASF<-t(matrix(py$X_gasf,ncol=length(py$X_gasf[,,1])))
```
````

But this is not what I want to have. I want to have something which would look like this:

````
```{r}
transform_to_gasf <- function(dummy){
  
require(reticulate); require(tibble)
pyts<- reticulate::import("pyts", convert = TRUE)
pytsImage<-reticulate::import("pyts.image", convert = TRUE)
x<-t(as.ts(dummy))

from pyts.image import GramianAngularField
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
gasf = GramianAngularField(image_size=15, method='summation')
X_gasf = gasf.fit_transform(r.x)
exit 

dummy_GASF<-t(matrix(py$X_gasf,ncol=length(py$X_gasf[,,1])))
  return(dummy_GASF)
}

```
````

But this does not work, as it throws an error "unexpected token" so it does not understand python syntax while written this way.

Comment: It seems that `reticulate`'s `source_python` function is useful. https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/source_python.html

Comment: I was trying to use it to no avail. I am clearly doing something wrong, which is why I asked for a dummy function example.

Comment: “I am clearly doing something wrong” Can you provide some more specific message?

Comment: I clarified within the question.